# Take the number from two different functions and add them together in another function (Unique to Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a simple function that will add one number to another to get a total amount, seems easy right? Thats what I thought although I am new to javascript and I believe Google Apps Script could also playing with me.

Here is a stripped down code of that exact function that is WORKING with manually inputted figures.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Calculator - V1</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>

      function showHourlyRate() {
        var oneFunc = 1
        console.log(oneFunc) //result is 5.00
        // alert(oneFunc);
        return oneFunc
      };

      function showMileageRate() {
        var twoFunc = 1
        console.log(twoFunc) //result is 5.00
        // alert(twoFunc);
        return twoFunc
      };
      function showCombinedFigure() {
        var twoFunc = showHourlyRate() + showMileageRate()
        alert(twoFunc);
      };

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showCombinedFigure);
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

That takes the showHourlyRate and showMileageRate figures and adds them together to make 2, perfect.

I need to get those figures from a Google Sheets doc so (using google apps script application to code) I have 3 files, one is the default Code.gs file. I have then created a functions.gs file and an index.html file.

Here's my Code.gs file

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
 
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

I believe you need this in order for it all to run and it basically just says to use the index.html file.

Here's my functions.gs file

```
function getHourlyRate() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("643876537465743653456").getSheetByName("Working Hours");
  const data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 8).getValues();
  const filteredData = data.filter(r => r[0] === "Sundries");

  return filteredData.length === 0 ? 0 : filteredData.reduce((subtotal, r) => subtotal + r[1], 0).toFixed(2);
  
}

function getMileageRate() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("643876537465743653456").getSheetByName("Working Hours");
  const data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 8).getValues();
  const filteredData = data.filter(r => r[0] === "Mileage");

  return filteredData.length === 0 ? 0 : filteredData.reduce((subtotal, r) => subtotal + r[1], 0).toFixed(2);
  
}
```

This is where I get the google sheets information, it finds the doc by ID, then finds the sheet by name, selects the rows I want to search then filters the results based on my chosen word.

Finally my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Calculator - V1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>

      function afterSidebarLoads() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showHourlyRate).getHourlyRate(); 
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showMileageRate).getMileageRate();
      }

      function showHourlyRate(hourlyRate) {
        var oneFunc = hourlyRate
        console.log(oneFunc) //result is 5.00
        //alert(oneFunc);
        return oneFunc
      };

      function showMileageRate(mileageRate) {
        var twoFunc = mileageRate
        console.log(twoFunc) //result is 5.00
        //alert(twoFunc);
        return twoFunc
      };
      function showCombinedFigure() {
        var twoFunc = showHourlyRate() + showMileageRate()
        alert(twoFunc);
      };

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", afterSidebarLoads);
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showCombinedFigure);
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Now it no longer works. The alerts for the showHourlyRate() and showMileageRate() work (when activated) and shows the correct figures. The alert for showCombinedFigure() no longer works, I get a NAN error, if I remove '+ showMileageRate()' like so:

```
      function showCombinedFigure() {
        var twoFunc = showHourlyRate() + showMileageRate()
        alert(twoFunc);
      };
```

I get undefined error.

I'm not exactly sure what this function does but is this the culprit? I followed a guide to get me to the point of reading the data from the sheets doc but now I need to move further along.

```
      function afterSidebarLoads() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showHourlyRate).getHourlyRate(); 
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showMileageRate).getMileageRate();
      }
```

Comment: Do you need hourly rate and mileage rates?

Comment: Yes, basically this is the start of a calculator. I want to get multiple values and add them together, I'll then create an input box that will have a quantity and times the value by that quantity giving me a total price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values returned by `showMileageRate` and `showHourlyRate` aren't being stored anywhere, you'll want to change your functions to store them globally:

```
<script>
      let oneFunc
      let twoFunc

      function afterSidebarLoads() {
        // get mileage rate
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(mileageRateHandler).getMileageRate()

      }
      
      function mileageRateHandler(mileageRate) {
        // set gloabal oneFunc
        oneFunc = mileageRate

        // get hourly rate
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(hourlyRateHandler).getHourlyRate()
      }

      function hourlyRateHandler(hourlyRate) {
        // set global twoFunc
        twoFunc = hourlyRate
        
        // call showCombinedFigure after both Apps Script methods have completed
        showCombinedFigure()
      }

      function showCombinedFigure() {
        var result = oneFunc + twoFunc
        alert(result);
      };

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", afterSidebarLoads);
  </script>
```

Also you need to make sure that `showCombinedFigure` runs only after the Apps Script functions have returned, as `google.script.run` is an asynchronous function and returns after the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.

Comment: Thanks but that makes no difference. It still comes up NAN or undefined

Comment: Ah, I see now, it's an async issue. `google.script.run` runs asynchornously so `showCombinedFigure` is run before the values are set. I've edited my code

Comment: Hi, I'm guessing you forgot to change the function names in the showCombinedFigure function? I changed these to match the new functions names and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, should just be `oneFunc + twoFunc`

Comment: Thank you. I edited the result variable line to make it work 'var result = Number(oneFunc) + Number(twoFunc)' but it all appears to work now.